# Columns total in row and transpose (SQL server)

Tags: sql-server, transpose

I have the following data set:

```
Account|Can|Fra|scl|
1012    0    10   1
1011    5    10   0
```

How can I get the total by each column in a row first :

```
Account|Can|Fra|scl|
1012    0    10   1
1011    5    10   0
Total   5    20   1
```

and then transpose it so it looks like this:

```
Can 5
Fra 20
Scl 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should help you. It will avoid an unnecessary intermediate step. You can directly get the final result with below query

```
SELECT 'CAN' AS COUNTRY, SUM(CAN) AS COUNTVAL FROM MY_TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'FRA' AS COUNTRY, SUM(FRA) AS COUNTVAL FROM MY_TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SCL' AS COUNTRY, SUM(SCL) AS COUNTVAL FROM MY_TABLE
```

[**Working fiddle - 1 here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99ff8e/1)

If you want to get the total of each column, then you can use:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, CAN, FRA,SCL FROM MY_TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL' AS ACCOUNT, SUM(CAN) AS CAN, SUM(FRA) AS FRA, SUM(SCL) AS SCL 
       FROM MY_TABLE
```

[**Working fiddle - 2 here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99ff8e/1)